# sed expressions: line shows twice

Tags: sed

I'm parsing a csv file with a `sed` command like this:

```
sed -n -e 's/abc/&/p' -e 's/xyz/&/p' <input >output
```

Now if there is both in one line (`abc` and `xyz`) I'll have the line twice in the output. I'd should have it just once.

Can I do that with `sed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to print a line with "abc" or "xyz":

```
sed -n '/abc\|xyz/p'
```

Other tools:

```
grep -F -e abc -e xyz
awk '/abc/ || /xyz/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mis-using the s///p just to print the lines. This is not necessary in sed - you can get them printed using //p.

Both expressions will evaluate, though, so you are still at risk of duplication. Your best bet (and fastest, for large datasets) will be to build the 'or' behavior into the matching regexp:

```
sed -Ene '/abc|xyz/p' input >output
```

Comment: what version of sed has `-E`? Is this some flavour of BSD?

Comment: Yes. -E triggers "modern" regex mode, which changes \| into |.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n -r -e 's/(abc|xyz)/&/p' <input >output
```

`-r` flag is for enabling extended regular expressions (is in GNU sed)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/abc/{p;b
   }
/xyz/p' Input > Output
```

for non GNU sed (where `|` is not allowed as OR)